# Terminal specific tmux colors

Tags: tmux

I use tmux mainly on two different terminal emulators (st and konsole) and on the tty. I would like to customize the statusbar colors according to the terminal that I'm using. I know that there is a way to do it, but I'm not familiar with tmux config.

Answer (score 0):

If they have different `TERM` you can use the `client_termtype` format, something like:

```
#{?#{m:st*,#{client_termtype}},#[bg=red]st,#[bg=blue]konsole}
```

Comment: can you please explain this ?#{   ,  ,  , } syntax?